# Why is my iPhone clock running behind 20 min?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone clock is at 15:32 when the actual time is at 15:52! why is it twenty minutes behind?

The time zones are all correct and I have a screenshot that I will upload soon.

Comment: Do you live in area with daylight savings?

Comment: Some guy reported something similar (30 mins) over on SU yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem and this solved it.

Check that your time is set automatically by going to Settings.app -> General -> Date & Time -> Set Automatically to 'ON'

Comment: A reboot fixes it, but my question was **WHY**

Answer (score 1):

It will also update if you just go to airplane mode and back out.
And if you ever lose signal and get it back.

It gets info from tower (or repeater). Towers are correct, but many repeaters are old and cannot be remotely administered thus can have bad time on them. If you lose signal then get signal again from a repeater (common in cities with tall builidings) it could be wrong depending how old it is.